# Azure Stream Analytics and PowerBI DAX

Tags: azure, dax, powerbi, azure-stream-analytics

We have our Azure Stream Analytics setup so that it

1. Has an input: Azure Storage Blobs (alias named: blobinput)
2. Has an output: PowerBI (alias named: powerbioutput)
3. Has a query

   `SELECT * INTO powerbioutput FROM blobinput TIMESTAMP BY RequestDateTime`
4. Run the Azure Stream Analytics job.

We are able to write into PowerBI and the Dataset and Table is populated appropriately.

To perform a proper analysis of our data, we need to create a few derived tables and columns from our dataset, however

- We seem to be unable to find where to define DAX queries from the [PowerBI](https://app.powerbi.com/) website for this Dataset and Table.
- We seem to be unable to find a way to export the Datasets created by Azure Stream Analytics to the PowerBI Desktop application.
- We are unable to create multiple Azure Stream Analytics Job Outputs that write to the same Dataset but different Tables in PowerBI.

Comment: I think you are right those are current limitations of Power BI. I would recommend you post suggestions at the following link if they don't already exist. And post the suggestion links here in your question so that others can vote. https://ideas.powerbi.com

Answer (score 2):

You can in fact create multiple outputs for the same job.  See announcement here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/streamanalytics/archive/2015/03/27/support-for-multiple-outputs-job-health-alerts-improved-query-testing.aspx

You need to create multiple outputs and then use the INTO clause and comma separate the various outputs and ensure they accept the same formats.

Comment: But I think @Aditya is right that you can't have Stream Analytics write to two separate tables in the same Power BI dataset currently.

Comment: @GregGalloway, That is correct! I have tried creating 2 outputs writing to different tables in the same dataset. However this approach fails (with an error that says that the datasets need to be unique for each output) once the Azure Stream Analytics job is started.